# Connection Issues When Disabling Security

Tags: appfabric

I'm playing around with an AppFabric security configuration. The issue is when I use the standard configuration it works fine:

Configuration:
Set-CacheClusterSecurity -SecurityMode Transport -ProtectionLevel EncryptAndSign

Code:

```
var configuration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
        configuration.Servers = new[]
                                    {
                                        new DataCacheServerEndpoint("server1.domain.net", 22233),
                                        new DataCacheServerEndpoint("server2.domain.net", 22233),
                                        new DataCacheServerEndpoint("server3.domain.net", 22233),
                                    };

        configuration.SecurityProperties = new DataCacheSecurity();

        _factory = new DataCacheFactory(configuration);
```

When I modify the security configuration on both the client and server I get an error:

Configuration: Set-CacheClusterSecurity -SecurityMode None -ProtectionLevel None

Code:

```
var configuration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
        configuration.Servers = new[]
                                    {
                                        new DataCacheServerEndpoint("server1.domain.net", 22233),
                                        new DataCacheServerEndpoint("server2.domain.net", 22233),
                                        new DataCacheServerEndpoint("server3.domain.net", 22233),
                                    };

        configuration.SecurityProperties = new DataCacheSecurity(DataCacheSecurityMode.None, DataCacheProtectionLevel.None);

        _factory = new DataCacheFactory(configuration);
```

Error:
Exception:ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. 
Please retry later. (One or more specified Cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client account on the cluster and that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all cache hosts. 
Retry later.)

The only difference is the security configuration on the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart the cluster in order to apply the new settings to the server.

Comment: It ended up being a security issue running the appfabric caching api within a classic asp web application. Thanks for the tip though.